# Some users report losing data

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

After a long time having an app run without any problems - I got a report form a user stating the data / photos saved was lost now and then. I.e. it may work initially, but at a later stage the content appear gone. I can not duplicate the problem, so I am trying to see if I can "guess" it.

First thing to ensure is that I am not saving data in a way that is somehow not feasible with recent Android versions. Hence here is how I currently save data:

...

First try

```
File storage_files_dir_file = ctx.getExternalFilesDir("");
if (storage_files_dir_file.exists() == false) {
  return false;
}
// ... some code here prepping content
os = new FileOutputStream(path_final,true);
// ... some code here writing content
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctx, new String[] {s}, null, null);
return true
```

If the above returns false switch to

```
File storage_files_dir_file = ctx.getFilesDir();
if (storage_files_dir_file.exists() == false) {
  return false;
}
// ... some code here prepping content
os = new FileOutputStream(path_final,true);
// ... some code here writing content
return true
```

...

My AndroidManifest.xml includes

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

...

If indeed it is a file problem I see the following possibilities:

- Data access issue?
- The saved files get removed by Android?
- 3rd party cleaning app?
- Related to if running on phones with a SD card in bay?
- Related to if running on phones with app installed on SD card in bay?
- Phone running completely out of space?
- **New**: Android 8 users deleting data and photos by accident?
- **New**: Combination of Android 8 + e.g. either external app data or internal app data.

It is has been a long while since I coded the above - but I recall the ambition was to save the data at as permanent and accessible place as possible for easy backup.

...

My last update to the app was in March 2017.

***Update***

I am wondering if the culprit of the problem could be Android 8 Oreo. I have not had access to his myself yet, but from articles it seems it is now possible to delete photos across apps in one go? + I have seen screenshots where users can select to delete both app-data and app-cache? If this is the reason: Any difference if using external or internal app-data storage? Or way to prevent?

My app data is not affected by any cleanup app I have tried on Android 6 and Android 7, but I only tried a quite limited amount compared to all the different companies out there producing Android phones.

...

Does anyone know if it possible to get a file deletion log from users they can send? Maybe that would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: If you save data in getExternalFilesDir, you have no control on the content. As you said, it can be a user mistake, or a third-party app that does cleanup.

Comment: Are you sure, that you are requesting permissions correctly? From Android O you have to request Read & Write storage permission separately. Prior to that requesting for Read permission used to grant Write permission automatially

Comment: @sagar I use: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Are you requesting this permission? The above declaration will only notify that you are using the permission

Comment: Have you tested on Androud 8.0? And checked if this permission is granted?

Comment: @Sagar still trying to obtain Android 8 - currently I have a SO about Android Studio 3.0 upgrade broke my project, so can not compile right now. But I have been trying to locate people with an Android 8 phone near my vicinity, so I could test real-world with the existing app in app store..

Comment: You dont need a phone to test this behaviour. Just use an emulator. Dowload it through Android studio

Comment: Meanwhile you can update your question with the code you use to request permission.

Comment: @Sagar - I don't think it is permission issue:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String) "Starting in KITKAT, no permissions are required to read or write to the returned path; it's always accessible to the calling app. This only applies to paths generated for package name of the calling application" which is what I use. (And app also seems to work as expected in 8.0 and 8.1 Android simulator - been performing a wide range of tests)

Comment: @Tom what was your solution in the end?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem sounds more like an external cleanup of any kind to be honest.

But anyway, maybe you want to take a look at this:
We had issues with a file generated too since Android 8, I then came upon this article:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

We changed our file access to be done via such providers and everything is fine since then.
Hope this helps,
Cheers Gris

Comment: If I e.g. use the built-in storage cleanup tools on Huawei phones on Android 6 and 7 the app data files are not removed. However - yes - by the description I have been provided - my guess is the user(s) are removing data themselves. The problem seems to happen for a few users... Seems to correlate fairly nice with Android 8 roll-out since essentially they have had the app over two years without any such problem reported.

I am using FileProvider when taking photos with the camera - but they then get saved/retrieved using the above code - think diary like app.

Answer (score 2):

**- getExternalFilesDir()**

> If you have files that are tied to your application that are simply
>   too big to risk putting in internal storage, or if the user should be
>   able to download the files off their device at will, you can use
>   **`getExternalFilesDir()`**, available on any activity or other Context. This will give you a File object pointing to an
>   automatically-created directory on external storage, unique for your
>   application. While not secure against other applications, it does have
>   one big advantage: **when your application is uninstalled, these files
>   are automatically deleted**, just like the ones in the
>   application-local file area.

---

**- getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()**

> If you have files that belong more to the user than to your app -
>   pictures taken by the camera, downloaded MP3 files, etc. - a better
>   solution is to use
>   **`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`**, available on the Environment class. This will give you a File object pointing to a
>   directory set aside for a certain type of file, based on the type you
>   pass into **`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`**. For example, you
>   can ask for `DIRECTORY_MOVIES`, `DIRECTORY_MUSIC`, or
>   `DIRECTORY_PICTURES` for storing MP4, MP3, or JPEG files,
>   respectively. **These files will be left behind when your application
>   is uninstalled**.

so to prevent data lost when user deletes app data , you can use  `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` instead of `getExternalFilesDir()` If you have **files that belong more to the user than to your app**

Comment: Hi - thank you for trying to help. The data (including photos - but there is associated text and stats data as well) belongs to the combination of app and user + preferably has to be readily available to the user if connecting over USB PC/Mac. Hence using getExternalFilesDir() to get app specific directory.